# Scanner (Getinputstream()) throws exception returns no line found from URL connection

Tags: java, url, web-scraping, java.util.scanner, yahoo-finance

I am trying to write a Java program, which establishes connection to yahoo finance, and pulls some data of the website for a specific stock.

The program terminates with the exception no line found, which is thrown at the if(input.hasNextLine()) statement. I get what the exception mean, but i Can't figure out what the error is.

I know that the problem is not in the URL construction, because the URL downloads the requested data from the web, when copied into a web browser.

hopes someone can point me in the right direction, i have been puzzled for several hours, trying to search the forum, but no luck so far.

My code looks as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Download {
    public Download(String symbol, GregorianCalendar end, GregorianCalendar start){

        //Creates the URL
        String url = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol+
                     "&a="+start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
                     "&b="+start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
                     "&c="+start.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
                     "&d="+end.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
                     "&e="+end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
                     "&f="+end.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
                     "&g=d&ignore=.csv";

        try{
        //Creates the URL object, and establishes connection    
        URL yhoofin = new URL(url); 
        URLConnection data = yhoofin.openConnection();
        //Opens an input stream, to read from
        Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");

        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        //skips the first line, 
            if(input.hasNextLine()){
                input.nextLine();
                //tries to print the data.
                    while(input.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
            }
        //closes connection
        input.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);

        }



    }




}
```

with the following main method:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2015,7,10);
    GregorianCalendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2016,7,10);
    String symbol ="NVO";
    Download test = new Download(symbol,end,start);
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}

Comment: Throws what exception?

Comment: sorry, missed   a line in the code last night, just added it above the if(input.hasNextLine()).  The exception that gets thrown is: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found.   which i ques is because the stream is empty. But i don't know how i should go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ABCB4.SA&a=1&b=19&c=2017&d=2&e=19&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv
    String url = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol+".SA"+
            "&a="+start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
            "&b="+start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
            "&c="+start.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
            "&d="+end.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
            "&e="+end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
            "&f="+end.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
            "&g=d&ignore=.csv";

    System.out.println(url);

    try
    {
        URL yhoofin = new URL(url);
        URLConnection data = yhoofin.openConnection();
        data.connect();//not necessary
        System.out.println("Connection Open! = "+data.getHeaderFields().toString());

        String redirect = data.getHeaderField("Location");
        if (redirect != null){
            data = new URL(redirect).openConnection();
        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        System.out.println();
        in.readLine();//skip first line
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            lines.add(inputLine);
        }
```

Comment: the lines.add(inputLine) at end is a ArrayList of Strings that i use to keep the lines in memory. Im using for São Paulo Stock Market, the link is different, u must use the same as the old one that work for u.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Even more: dont add further explanations as comments. Edit your answer. Plus: spend that 1 minute it takes to **properly** format/indent all of the source code. It is bad enough that the OP is posting such a mess, but you shouldnt do that again!